# Awarding Downtime Days Using Rules-as-Intended

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, downtime

I am currently DMing a group through **CCC-YLRA01-02 Uneasy Lies the Head**. They are all experienced DMs so it resembles a Dentist Convention (but sexier of course!). We are having a slight disagreement over the amount of Downtime due.

On page 5 of the "**D&D Adventurers League Player's Guide Version 7.0**" (which is available here: www.dmsguild.com) The exact wording is:

> Characters earn downtime at the rate of 5 downtime days per 2 hours of
>   prescribed adventure length (or 5 downtime days for every 2 cumulative
>   hours of play for Hardcover adventures)."

**CCC-YLRA01-02 Uneasy Lies the Head** is described as

> A 4-hour adventure for 5th-10th level characters

So according to RAW the players should get 10 Downtime days in total. Having said that, I have spoken to several convention organizers who ran the mod as well as local DMs and everyone agrees the time was grossly underestimated. In the case of my own group, we will hopefully complete this in 12 hours.

**CCC-YLRA01-02** also states on Page 31 that

> the characters earn downtime and renown in accordance with the
>   guidance prescribed by the Adventurers League Dungeon Master's Guide.

So my question is as follows: As the DM, and according to AL rules, am I allowed to award 10 Downtime days per 4-hour session, (which in this case will amount to 30 Downtime days), or do I have to limit it to 10 days?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you are not allowed to award 30 days.

AL has rules for everyone to follow and in this case it’s very clear from the rules what the allowed award is.

If you believe an exception is merited, contact your local AL organizer and make the request. It seems reasonable, but what they don't want is "individual tables just make it all up as they go," for campaign-wide fairness reasons.

Comment: There are no "local organizers" with any authority to adjudicate anything - the only body with any authority is the actual DDAL admins.

Answer (score 8):

If you are playing an adventure with a set time length you are beholden to the awards for those times. If you're playing a hardcover adventure with no time given then you use actual time played.